# Connect Android application to remote MSSQL Database using webservices

Tags: android, web-services

We are working on google calendar application in android. We need to
connect our application to remote MSSQL Database using webservices. We are
new to webservices in android. Can you please provide us some code on how to
use webservices to conect to Mssql server.
We have used php scripts for connecting our login page and we have
written this code without using webservices.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

here is a [link](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/). This example shows that how to connect android to mysql via php. I hope this will help you.

Comment: If you want me to implement that i can help you.

Comment: We are using remote MSSQL Server for connecting our android application. So can you please send us a sample php script for MSSQL? It will be helpful for us.....

Comment: you send me the neccesary details about  project to my email address, so that i can send you php script of it.

Comment: Can you please give us your email address?

Comment: Can you please give us your email address?

Comment: We sent mail to you , Thank you